# Laravel direcionando método HTTP para função errada no Controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, vue.js

Tenho um projeto em `Laravel` e `Vue.js` onde tenho uma função no `Vue.js` que manda um post com os dados de um formulário, até aí tudo bem, só que quando a função `this.$http.post()` faz a requisição para o back-end, o laravel direciona para o método errado, ele deveria mandar para o método `store`(que trata das requisições post), porém envia para o método index(responsável pelas requisições GET), um detalhe é que estou usando `RestFull Controllers`, então todos os métodos estão sendo acessados com base na requisição que está sendo feita(ou pelo menos deveria ser assim).

Um detalhe é que localmente na máquina que utilizo para desenvolver funciona perfeitamente, e numa outra máquina servidora local, também funciona perfeitamente, agora colocar esse projeto no servidor de produção da Amazon acontece o que relatei acima.

As configurações são as seguintes:

> Máquina local
>
> PHP 5.6.28

---

> Servidor Local
>
> PHP 7.0

---

> Servidor do Amazon(EC2)
>
> PHP 5.6.30

---

O que pode estar acontecendo? Realmente já pensei em várias possibilidades e não tenho ideia do que pode ser.

Comment: Edita a pergunta e adiciona os códigos referentes ao problema, tais como o código JS que faz a requisição e o código do controlador do Laravel que possui os métodos `index` e `store`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei a solução, na verdade encontrei a resposta no fórum estrangeiro, o que estava acontecendo era que a url nos métodos $http estavam com uma "/"(barra) no final, por exemplo: 
"test.com/api/v1/resource/"

foi só tirar ficando assim:
"test.com/api/v1/resource"

fazendo isso deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Acontece que quando se trabalhar com o VueResource, em alguns projetos você precisa dizer a ele para emular uma requisição normal como HTTP.

Para realizar esta configuração, adicione o parâmetro de Configs ao VueResource, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
var config = {
    emulateJSON: true,
    emulateHTTP: true
};

// Adicionado o CONFIG para emular
this.$http.post(url, data, config).then((val) => {
    console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: Nos métodos http já inclui as configurações acima, porém sem o emulateHTTP, tentei com e não adiantou também.